# Why h1 cannot ping h2 in mininet?

Tags: mininet, openflow

I created a minimal network without a controller, like this:

```
sudo mn --controller none
```

Then I add a record to flow-table of s1, like this:

```
dpctl add-flow in_port=all,action=flood
```

However h1 ping h2 still failed. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Mininet uses Open vSwitch as its virtual switches. And OvS will not allow you to match multiple ports at the same time. I've heard about bitwise mask in matching fields but not tried ever.  Maybe you can search for this.

Besides, "all" in a OpenFlow switch is a reserved port used in reservation of specific actions.

To do the same things in your work, you may want to try this:

```
dpctl add-flow in_port=1,action=flood
dpctl add-flow in_port=2,action=flood
```

And the ping can work.